# LARAVEL GET 404 (Not Found) when trying to load ui with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, laravel

I am trying to load a UI in a dashboard with **AJAX**. its purpose is to load **UI** without page refresh by clicking on a **ul**. it is working fine with normal PHP but when I use it in .blade.php it is showing the error 404(not found) the video link is here. [Video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12_1ifUTdud_zO9Y-DFES307KjoaS_CDr)

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var trigger = $('#navi ul li a'),
        container = $('#dataHere');
    trigger.on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this) target = $this.data('target');
        container.load(target + '.blade' + '.php');
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

i need help with this
thanks in advance.

Comment: you should add your jquery code here

Comment: <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var trigger = $('#navi ul li a'),
            container = $('#dataHere');
            trigger.on('click', function(){
            var $this = $(this)
            target = $this.data('target');
            container.load(target +'.blade'+'.php');
            return false;
            });
          });
  </script>

Comment: have you defined your routes in routes/web.php?

Comment: we cant see any code ?

Comment: yes.....here is web.php

Comment: @NipunTharuksha i'll add it now

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46448937/laravel-include-a-blade-view-via-ajax/46456355

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812785/how-to-load-blade-or-php-content-into-a-view-via-ajax-jquery-in-laravel

Comment: @NipunTharuksha yes i have

Comment: @NipunTharuksha How can we connect

Comment: @Sehdev this is not resolved yet..

Comment: @NipunTharuksha so where should i send you the address???

Comment: lets get into chat rather than commenting. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207513/discussion-between-nipun-tharuksha-and-babar-raza

Comment: You should NOT load blade files directly...

Comment: @Jerodev so what should i load???

Comment: A route that renders this file

Comment: https://laracasts.com/series/javascript-techniques-for-server-side-developers/episodes/1

Comment: @Rwd Bro you Great It Worked Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can not request a blade file from the front-end, you can only access files that are in the /public folder.

If you like to load a blade template with Ajax you can create another public function in your controller, setup a route and request that location from your ajax call.

Comment: Great, don't forget to flag the answer as correct to help others.

Comment: While explanations are good, this answer doesn't show any code of how to do such things.